# cURL input to DOMDocument UTF-8

Tags: php, curl, utf-8, domdocument, windows-1252

I am reading in the HTML from a URL and even though it is labelled as UTF-8 in the browser I have to iconv Windows-1252//IGNORE to get the correct result.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 10;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $html = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252//IGNORE", $html);

    echo ($html);
```

Output (long HTML file and raw output):`<span class="price">€30 and under</span>`

To parse through the DOMDocument I tried different ways including enforcing UTF-8 encoding but basically

```
        $tmp = new DOMDocument();
       //$tmp->encoding = 'UTF-8';
       $tmp->loadHTML($html);
       echo $tmp->saveXML();
```

which outputs the HTML as `<span class="price">&#x80;30 and under</span>`. This character is a Windows 1252 Character for €, but I cannot figure out how to convert it back to the original (same for other special characters).

Thanks for any ideas on how to explain or fix this really strange DOMDoc behaviour!

fj

Comment: What does the original HTML look like? What are you trying to do with the HTML? Why are you using `saveXML()` if it's not XML?

Comment: saveHTML() does not make a difference. I am parsing the result to an overview page for the user and enter it into a database for future reference.

Comment: This is not strange behviour on the part of DomDocument, you are passing it cp1251 text so it will output entities accordingly. You should share the original HTML, and if possible a link to the live file, in case server misconfiguration is the problem.